# Upgrading to wifi thermostat

Tags: hvac

I have a 24v power supply attached to y and c on furnace terminal block with with regular y,w,r,g and what looks like a c wire to ac coming from inside furnace. I have a wire on y,w,g and 2 on r at thermostat.I'm guessing power supply was added to furnace to power digital thermostat I'm replacing. How do I install wifi thermostat correctly.

Comment: It may help to specify the furnace make & model as well as the thermostat make & model you're trying to connect.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the furnace, as well as the furnace's wiring diagram?

Comment: Goodman 92% high efficiency. Can't add photos here. If you want to post email I will send you photos of terminal block and thermostat.

Comment: Honeywell 8400c to Honeywell rth6580wf

Comment: Posted photos of terminal block/thermostat @StackOverflow  twitter

Comment: @Scott -- hit the [edit] link at the bottom left of your post in "share edit ..." while logged in (it may say "improve your post", that's OK), then use the "mountain and sun" button on the editor toolbar to add photos